# Why panning google map updates angularjs scope var?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

Kind of an odd question/hard to find an answer. I'm relatively new to using angularjs and have a problem i'm confused about.

I've set up a google map using http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/ and have an issue.

So i have a $scope.homeBase where i am setting a lat & long for the owners 'Home Base', i want to use that location to set the on load map center, & a pin to show the location. So in my mind cool, set the one var and use it in both locations. Wrong.

So this works on load, but every time i pan the map, i guess it re-sets the map center location, which in turn binds to the map marker and sends the marker to the middle of the screen, on every pan.

Is there anyway to have the two not bound? or have separate vars? without them bound?

i thought a simple 'var homebase' would remove binding and not update the var. instead of using scope but it still binds?

This perhaps is a newb question but i appreciate any pointing in proper direction.

Thanks again

here's my code.

```
    // uiGmapGoogleMapApi is a promise, The "then" callback function provides a maps object.
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function() { 

    // Setting homebase coords, these will come from firebase
    $scope.homeBase = { latitude: -34.18405, longitude: 150.71319 }; 

    // Set default map.
    $scope.map = { 
        center: $scope.homeBase,
        pan: true,
        zoom: 14,
        events: {
            click: function(){

            }
        }
    };

    // Set homebase marker.
    $scope.homebaseMarker = {
      id: 0,
      coords: $scope.homeBase,
      options: { draggable: false },
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the center on page load via

```
 angular.copy(var)
```